# Electron with Touchbar: TouchBarLabel is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, electron

I'm using axios in my electron app to get data from an API. This data should be displayed on the touchbar once it's received. To manage the touchbar I added a new .ts file:

```js
import electron, {
    BrowserWindow,
    TouchBar,
    TouchBarLabel,
    TouchBarButton,
    TouchBarSpacer
} from "electron";
import { IProject } from './types';

export function updateTouchBar(data: IProject[]) {
    let arr = [];
    data.forEach(ele => {
        arr.push(new electron.TouchBarLabel({ label: ele.name }));
    });

    publish(new TouchBar({ items: arr }));
}

export function publish(tb: TouchBar) {
    electron.remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().setTouchBar(tb);
}
```

Displaying data in the window works, but the touchbar is not working: `TouchBarLabel is not a constructor`.

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Thanks,
Lukas

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue `TouchBarLabel is not a constructor.` and if your problem is anything like mine, the solution will be to rearrange the import statement like

```
import electron, { BrowserWindow, TouchBar } from "electron";
const { TouchBarLabel, TouchBarButton, TouchBarSpacer } = TouchBar;
```